# jQuery - Toggle, return to native when clicked again

Tags: jquery, html, css

Problem is [here](http://jaakkouusitalo.fi/test).

First blue block has `min-height of 500px`. It shows information about me. So viewer presses button called "Lue Lisää" (which means Read more). Blue block should change its height that it doesn't look messed up.

**This scenario should happen:**

- Press Lue Lisää
- Reveal more info
- Increase the height of blue block,
  so that it looks good. (auto or more than 500px)
- Return to the original size (500px) when clicked again.

**What scenario is happening:**

- Press Lue Lisää
- Reveal more info
- Increase the height of blue block
- **Doesn't return when I click again.**

  ```
      $(".more button:eq(0)").click(function(){
          $(".about").css("height", "630px");
          $(".visible:eq(0)").toggle('slow');
          $(".hidden:eq(0)").toggle('slow');  
      });
  ```

You can use `.css ("height", "toggle")`, but that just toggles between `0px` and original (`500px`).

Any workarounds here? Should I use `.animate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with moving around your CSS a little, I've had a quick play in firebug and I think it can be done without any forcing of heights which should make your head a little clearer!

Some changes I made:

```
#left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
}
#right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 39%; /* don't know why it doesn't like 100% total */
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: top; /* make the image stay at the top */
}
.grid { /* Remove the height, and add extra padding (margin removed on left and right) */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 150px 50px 50px;
    width: 860px;
}
```

These changes allow the content to just flow naturally - it was the floating that meant heights needed to be forced.

Comment: I started to think that It may just be my css that is bugging out. I tried to use min-height, because of these kind of errors but somehow it didnt work on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the toggleClass function.

```
$(".className").toggleClass("toggle-class");
```

Comment: Yes there is always that option, but isnt there really easier way to do it? I really would like to add animation later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggle()` and `animate` here, like this:

```
$('.about').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            height: "630"
        }, 500);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            height: "500"
        }, 500);     

    }
);
```

Comment: Apparently toggle doesn't work inside click function.